# Is it possibile to limit stacktrace to some package?

Tags: java, log4j2, printstacktrace

I'm using log4j2 to log my app, is it possibile to limit the stacktrace to some package? For example inside my packages and not after in the stack.

Now I'm getting a big stack thorught all Spring framework up to system Thread object and the end part of this stack is the same for all my exception, I only need the significant part.

Comment: Not really.  Why not just copy the text, paste it into a plain text editor, and delete the lines you don’t care about?

Comment: Because it fills my logs, this is not an issue, I only want to know if it is possibile.